# Categorical reason on why the tensor product of sheaves satisfies the universal property

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\sf{C}$ be a category. We denote by $\mathsf{C}_X$ the category of sheaves with values in $\mathsf{C}$ and by $\mathsf{C}_X^\text{pre}$ the category of presheaves with values in $\sf{C}$.

Since the sheafification functor is left-adjoint to the inclusion, limits in $\mathsf{C}_X$ are the same as limits in $\mathsf{C}_X^\text{pre}$, where they are calculated pointwise. Similarly, colimits in $\mathsf{C}_X$ are the sheafification of the colimits in $\mathsf{C}_X^\text{pre}$, where they are also calculated pointwise. This allows us to do basically all the interesting constructions.

In $\sf{Ring}$ this reasoning shows us that the presheaf defined by $(\mathscr{F}\otimes\mathscr{H})(U):=\mathscr{F}(U)\otimes \mathscr{H}(U)$ satisfies the universal property of the tensor product in $\mathsf{Ring}_X^\text{pre}$ and that, if $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{H}$ are sheaves, its sheafification satisfies the universal property of the tensor product in $\mathsf{Ring}_X$.

This same reasoning doesn't work in many other interesting categories ($\sf{Ab}$ and $A\textsf{-Mod}$, for example) since the tensor product need not be a colimit. Is there a categorical reason for the tensor product to be defined pointwise in these cases? (If this is true at all.)

Comment: Your remark about the tensor product of commutative rings is incorrect. It is a _coproduct_ so, as you say, you have to sheafify. The tensor product of modules has a universal property but it is not a limit or colimit. There is a way to generalise it to sheaves of modules, of course, but I don't know a general procedure that works for all kinds of universal properties.

Comment: @ZhenLin You're absolutely right. I'll edit the post now. What would you say is the natural notion of the tensor product of a sheaf of $A$-modules, for example? It is the sheafification of the sheaf defined pointwise? Even if it doesn't satisfy a usual universal property?

Comment: Yes, it is the sheafification. You can check that it has the appropriate universal property.

Comment: @ZhenLin, If $A$ is a sheaf, this indeed works. But I was thinking about a ring. In this case, what it even means to say that a sheaf of $A$-modules satisfies the universal property of the tensor product?

Comment: I find it puzzling that you say you understand what is happening when $A$ is a sheaf, which is the more difficult case. If $A$ is just a ring, promote it to a sheaf using the constant sheaf functor.